# Is there a quick comparison list of the different Warhammer 40k Space Marines Chapters?

Tags: warhammer-40k

As per the title, I'm wondering if there is a comparison list/tool somewhere that show the difference between the different Space Marines Chapter.

I'm starting Warhammer 40K with my son and I understand each chapter has different special abilities. Obviously we can't buy ALL the different codex to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Space Marines are part way through a redux at the moment so a few chapters are still waiting for new books (Imperial Fists and Salamanders) which should launch shortly.

The tactics pages on 1d4chan can be useful but they are not family friendly! The go into a lot of detail but the pros/cons section can give a good overview. The space marines page covers most loyal chapters and then the Dark Angels, Blood Angels, Space Wolves, Grey Knights and Deathwatch get their own pages.

Comment: I'm not sure I actually answered your question. Are you looking for a single page/table that compares them?

Comment: yes, I was looking for a comparison table.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I don't know of a source like that. If I find one I'll let you know.